# Can't add subdomain on LAMP VM Instance on Google Compute Engine

Tags: apache, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to add the `blog.mydomain.com` subdomain in Apache on a Google Cloud LAMP VM Instance.

In the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder there are three files: `default`, `default-ssl`, and `lamp-server`. I assumed `lamp-server` is the file being used, so I copied this file to `blog.mydomain.com` and edited the contents to be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias blog.mydomain.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.mydomain.com/
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/blog.mydomain.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After saving this new file I did `sudo a2ensite blog.mydomain.com` and then `service apache2 reload`. After doing this my main website (www.mydomain.com) went down and only would show a page that says "Error establishing a database connection". This message did not come from my application.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. If you add blog.mydomain.com by issuing a2ensite which creates virtualhost record in sites-available and in sites-enabled which shouldn't impact your original website unless you changes something.

If there is an entry for www.mydomain.com in the virtualhost and its goes to the right folder, you should not get "Error establishing a database connection" I'm guessing this is a wordpress instance.

Make sure your blog.mydomain.com points to the server ip address. Ping it before adding it to the servers web servers configuration.

Also get rid of these lines from the blog.mydomain.com configuration:

```
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
```

and restart the web server and load blog.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com.

The message `"Error establishing a database connection"` is probably coming from the `/var/www/blog.mydomain.com/` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Before I created the other file in `sites-available`, there were three files in that folder: `lamp-server`, `default`, and `default-ssl`. I duplicated `lamp-server` and renamed it to `blog.mydomain.com` and edited that file. Was that the right thing to do?

Comment: Also, blog.mydomain.com is WordPress, but www.mydomain.com is not. I'm getting the error when I go to www.mydomain.com, so I guess somehow the blog virtualhost is overriding the www virtualhost.

Comment: Thanks, your comment pointed me in the right direction. I had to duplicate `lamp-server` again and create a new file for mydomain.com and add that also using `a2ensite`.